# Setting updated token in the req.user session in Node

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

So here I have a route to call an API, sending to it the users token. The API then generates a new token and sends it back in the response.

I then want to update the `req.user.token` with the new token so I can continue making valid API calls in the session. However I can only do this for the session outside the scope of the response.

Here is my attempt. How can I make `req.user.token` take the updated token?

```
router.post('/:id', function (req, res, next) {

    var returnedToken = "";

    var options = {
        url: configUrl + '/' + req.params.id,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'token': req.session.passport.user.token,
            'caller': 'client[route:POST user]',
            'x-request-id': req.requestId,
        },
        json: req.body
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            req.logger.error({err: error}, 'connection to user service has failed');
            res.status(500).send(error.message);
        } else {
            res.status(response.statusCode).send(body);
            returnedToken = response.body.token;
        }
        return next();
    })
    req.user.token = returnedToken;

});
```

If I set the `req.user.token` within the request then it isn't available elsewhere in the client. However if I set the `req.user.token` where I have above the `returnedToken` is undefined because obviously it's outside the scope.

Any ideas how I can work around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value in req.user.token before you sends a response.

req.user.token = returnedToken;
res.status(response.statusCode).send(body);

So that the same request will be available in next middleware too. Also if you want to remove the old session token from user you can do delete(req.user); With this you can delete the old token value from request object.

Comment: Thanks. That worked, sometimes it just need's fresh eyes!